# What does threadid bogus mon mean?

Tags: android

I am using a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and when I have multiple scheduled threads running I am getting `threadid=xx: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting` in LogCat.

Can anyone shed any light on what this means, is it bad and if so how do I stop it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link for the source for it... looks like something's trying to wake a thread that's not actually waiting. If nothing else is going wrong it's probably harmless.

http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#oOy_5JrVRNM/trunk/dalvik/vm/Sync.c&q=android%20threadid%20bogus&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc&l=530

Comment: thanks for that.  i will investigate further then and come back with what i find.

Comment: It is harmless.  Some code manages to hit this easily, most never see it.  The message is going away in a future release (because that bit of code got rewritten).